# How can I remove white margins from a pdf file?

Tags: spacing, graphics, pdf

I create a diagram in Visio and save as a pdf file. There is a large space between the text and the figure, as shown the following:

[image]

If I understand well, the problem can be boiled down: **how to save a diagram as a pdf file with zero margin** (top, bottom, left, right) in **Visio**.

PS: for the last spacing issue, add `\usepackage{caption}`.

Comment: This appears to be off-topic. Could you clarify? Apart from the fact that you are including the diagram in a `.tex` document, does this have anything to do with TeX?

Comment: @cfr the solution is `pdfcrop input.pdf output.pdf`.

Comment: That doesn't mean this is not off-topic. The *question* is off-topic, it seems to me. (Note that that solution doesn't actually answer the question, even if it answers a different one.)

Comment: The first two spaces can be clipped by the command `\includegraphics` which would make this an on-topic problem. But `pdfcrop` is more elegant of course. For the last spacing issue, we need to see an MWE. We cannot guess what is happening there. Maybe, this space is desired by your template.

Comment: @cfr thx for your reminder. I edit the title as `How can I remove white margins from a pdf file?`

Comment: You might consider no specifying that you want a Visio-solution in the question itself, as well. If `pdfcrop` and/or @LaRiFaRi 's solutions are acceptable, then you are happy to save the diagram as is *in Visio*, provided you can then crop appropriately *outside* Visio.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi for the last spacing issue, add `\usepackage{caption}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can remove white margins from a pdf file with `pdfcrop`, in the simplest version

```
pdfcrop file.pdf
```

which generates a maximally cropped output file named `file-crop.pdf`.
You can also specify new own margins in points (default is zero), and name your output file as you want, as in

```
pdfcrop --margins 10 input.pdf output.pdf
```

Comment: AWESOME!!!! that totally helped me save an inch or two of margin!